# JavaScript only file uploader with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, upload

Does anybody know how they do multi file upload using only Javascript only and still show smooth progress bar for each file? I've seen gmail, hotmail and amazon s3 do it.

Comment: thanks for the samples but is there a way to provide this upload functionality without using flash or HTML5? I don't think gmail uses flash, do they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery with HTML5 to do this , See this example
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5-upload/source/browse/trunk/example.html

Comment: Wouldn't have been my first choice. you're still dependent on javascript/html5 but you don't get the benefit of SWF/Silverlight fallback so you've basically ruled out IE entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/). Both provide SWF multiple file upload methods with progress bars but plupload also provides HTML5, Silverlight, BrowserPlus alternatives and a plain form fallback. Both are quite configurable but I use plupload for the extra levels of browser/plugin support.

NOTE: plupload site appears to be down, I'd assume this is temporary as the project is still active.

Answer (score 1):

An excelent plugin (if not the best) is Uploadify

http://www.uploadify.com/

Hope this helps. Cheers